# Unable to change activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, viewflipper

I'm having some trouble switching activities.  I'm thinking it has something to do with my viewflipper.  Whenever I click the button "Start Game" to switch to the game activity, it throws the error "thread main exiting due to uncaught exception".  Can anyone give me a hand?  I know for sure it cannot be the start game activity and its layout, both are too simple to fail.  Like I said, I think it has something to do with my viewflipper.  Going even further, I want to explain more.  The activity starts off with a view that has username, password, and login edittexts/buttons, then, when the user and pass is accepted, it flips the view to the main menu.  From there, you press start game.

```
 package com.login.test;

 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

 public class Login extends Activity {

public EditText username, password;
public Button loginbutton, start, stats;
public ViewFlipper flip;
public String dbu, dbp;
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Timer t = new Timer(); 
public static final String KEEP_INFO = "remeberinfo";

public void startgame() {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Game.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

}

public void seescore() {

    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Login.this, Score.class);
    startActivity(myIntent2);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);




    username = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);        
    loginbutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
    start = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.start);
    stats = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.stats);
    flip = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.flip);
    //when a view is displayed
    flip.setInAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
   //when a view disappears
    flip.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    final Toast accessdenied = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect username/password", 3);
    final Toast accessgranted = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in", 3);

    //calling for a stored data byte using sharedpreferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(KEEP_INFO,0);
    String keptusername = settings.getString("keptuser", "");
    String keptpassword = settings.getString("keptpass", "");

    username.setText(keptusername);
    password.setText(keptpassword);



    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View v) {

            dbu = (username.getText()).toString();
            dbp = (password.getText()).toString();

            try{

            }
            finally{
                if ((dbu.equals("crete"))&&(dbp.equals("monee"))){
                    username.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenloginbutton);
                    password.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenloginbutton);
                    loginbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenloginbutton);
                    accessgranted.show();
                    //setting and valuing a data byte using sharedpreferences
                    SharedPreferences info = getSharedPreferences(KEEP_INFO,0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = info.edit();
                    editor.putString("keptuser", dbu);
                    editor.putString("keptpass", dbp);
                    editor.commit();
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                        public void run() { 
                                handler.post(new Runnable() { 
                                        public void run() { 
                                            flip.showNext();
                                        } 
                                }); 
                            } 
                    }, 2000); 

                }
                else {

                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                            public void run() { 
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() { 
                                            public void run() { 
                                                username.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbutton);
                                                password.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbutton);
                                                loginbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbutton);
                                            } 
                                    }); 
                            } 
                    }, 3000); 

                    accessdenied.show();
                    username.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redloginbutton);
                    password.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redloginbutton);
                    loginbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redloginbutton);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startgame();

        }
    });

    stats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            seescore();

        }
    });

     }
 }
```

LOG CAT

```
 01-28 12:03:56.125: D/dalvikvm(322): GC freed 594 objects / 48504 bytes in 172ms
 01-28 12:03:57.065: D/dalvikvm(322): GC freed 49 objects / 1904 bytes in 131ms
 01-28 12:03:57.838: D/ViewFlipper(322): updateRunning() mVisible=true, mStarted=false,          mUserPresent=true, mRunning=false
 01-28 12:04:09.176: D/AndroidRuntime(322): Shutting down VM
 01-28 12:04:09.185: W/dalvikvm(322): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0x4001b188)
 01-28 12:04:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(322): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due      to uncaught exception
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:      Unable to find explicit activity class      {com.beeseries.contextclues/com.beeseries.contextclues.Game}; have you declared this      activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at      android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at      android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.beeseries.contextclues.Login.startgame(Login.java:29)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.beeseries.contextclues.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:136)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 01-28 12:04:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(322):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 01-28 12:04:09.315: I/dalvikvm(322): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 01-28 12:04:09.435: I/dalvikvm(322): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 01-28 12:04:12.485: I/Process(322): Sending signal. PID: 322 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post full logcat, so anyone can see exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't declare your Game Activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Game"
<!-- other attributes and also possible intent-filters.-->
 />
```